# Hidden bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Подскажите как на bootstrap 4 реализовать аналог class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" как на bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ `<div class="d-none d-md-block">Скрыто на экранах меньше lg</div>`